# Presto query not getting the correct values

Tags: sql, select, max, min, presto

Require your help please.

I have a table name wqmram and i want to calculate the min and max value for a column name s6 by month wise. Min value should not be zero as i want minimum value which is above zero.

```
I have written the below query:
SELECT min(s6) AS Mins6,
max(s6) AS Maxs6,
partition_0,
partition_1
FROM wqmram
WHERE cast(s6 AS decimal(30,2)) != 0.00
GROUP BY partition_0,partition_1
ORDER BY partition_0,partition_1;
```

partition_0 is year and patition_1 is month. I get the results as below which is wrong:

```
    Mins6   Maxs6   partition_0 partition_1
1   1017    996 2019    11
2   1002    994 2019    12
3   00.09   958 2020    01
4   00.01   997 2020    02
5   100 999 2020    03
6   100 999 2020    04
7   1   99  2020    05
8   1000    998 2020    06
```

If you see the above result then minimum values are coming greater than maximum values and that too they are wrong.

Can somebody please let me know what is the issue ?

Comment: What is the datatype of column  `s6`?

Comment: hi @GMB - data type for s6 is string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the string values to numbers before you compute their `min` and `max`, otherwise, they are compared string-wise; typically, `'996'` is greater than `'1017'`, since the former starts with `'9'`, while the latter starts with `'1'`.

It might be simpler to convert in a subquery rather than repeating the `cast()` expression in the outer query:

```
select 
    partition_0,
    partition_1
    min(s6) as mins6,
    max(s6) as maxs6
from (
    select partition_0, partition_1, cast(s6 as decimal(30,2)) s6 
    from wqmram
) t
where s6 != 0.00
group by partition_0,partition_1
order by partition_0,partition_1;
```

Comment: Thanks GMB for your help. It worked very well and thanks for the explanation.